# Twitter API Search Query

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, libcurl

Are lists not able to be included into Twitter API calls? I am using PHP to call through a feed that is based off of a search query API.

When I attempt to use something like:

'?q=%23swag+list%3Ayoutube%2Fmusic'

I end up getting the results from:

'?q=%23swag'

---

Am I incorrectly calling from the API? This is what I am basing my understanding off. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Answer (score 0):

Read through this document:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Essentially, I've come to the conclusion that list:name/list is not a supported search parameter because it is not found in this document, even though the the url:

'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23swag+list%3Ayoutube%2Fmusic'

contains only tweets containing the hashtag #swag from members of youtube's music list.